# n points permuted on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Here is a combinatorics problem that bothers me a lot. I am looking forward to a quick reply. Thanks in advance. Here goes the problem.
Initially there are $n$ points on a circle. We do permutation to these points in the following way: in each permutation, the neighbors of any points are different from that of last permutation. Find the maximum number of such permutation we can proceed.

Comment: This site works better if you tell us what you have tried

Comment: How many permutations did you find for $n=3,4,5,6$?

Comment: I just try to translate this into graph theorical language,but failed.

Comment: Suppose that "..different from that of last permutation" means "..different from those already matched in previous states", or not ?

Comment: ok,for n=3,4,5,there are 0,0,2.@G Cab,yes you are right

Comment: In graph theoretical language, you would be asking for the number of Hamilton cycles in $K_n \setminus C_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how many edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles exist on the complete graph of n vertices.

Every arrangement of people around a circle corresponds to a hamiltonian cycle on $K_n$, and if you want no neighbors repeated, then the cycles must be edge-disjoint.

There are $\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}$ such cycles, according to this:
[Number of edge disjoint Hamiltonian cycles in a complete graph with even number of vertices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881420/number-of-edge-disjoint-hamiltonian-cycles-in-a-complete-graph-with-even-number)

Therefore there are this many arrangements (including the first one).