# If 2n +1 guests are to attend n meetings at a round table, prove that guests can be seated so that each guest has different neighbors at each meeting.

Tags: combinatorics

If 2n +1 guests are to attend n meetings at a round table, prove that those guests can be seated so that each guest has different neighbors at each meeting.

So there are $2n!$ ways that we can seat people in general. I'm not sure how to implement the number of meetings into this.

Is that correct? Because I'm not sure, it looks too simple of an answer to be correct.

Comment: First... there are $(2n+1)!/(2n+1) = (2n)!$ ways the guests can sit at a round table.  This has nothing to do with the number of ways in which they can sequence how they sit across all $n$ meetings and has nothing to do with whether or not anyone had repeated sitting next to another person in that time.  You have not finished the problem.

Comment: You don't have to count the number of ways to seat them once, you need to show that you can seat them $n$ times without repeating neighbors.  For $n=2$ you could start with $12345$ by symmetry and then say $41532$ completes the requirement.  You need to show it works for any $n$.

Comment: I think I'm just not getting it, so if we have 2n! ways we can sit people in general and we have n meetings any number n that we would use would result in there being more ways to sit people than the number of meetings

Comment: So... imagine we have people: Adam, Bobby, Charles, Doug, ..., who I'll hereafter refer to by their first letter of their name.  Suppose without loss of generality that the first time we sat people down it so happened that A was sitting next to B and C.  When we go to the second meeting and we decide who is going to sit where, we don't want A to sit next to B and we don't want A to sit next to C since they've already had a chance to sit together.  We don't want to repeat any neighbor pairs.  So, maybe next time we'll have A sit next to D and E.  But we aren't just worried about A...

Comment: We want to prove that we can come up with a way in which the people can sit so that across all $n$ meetings, each person will have never sat next to the same other person more than once.  That is to say, each person will have sat with each other person exactly once.

Comment: Reworded in terms of graph theory... considering the complete graph $K_{2n+1}$, prove that you can find $n$ edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles, (*or if you prefer, in $K_n$ with $n$ odd you can find $\frac{n-1}{2}$ edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles*).  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946283/how-many-edge-disjoint-hamilton-cycles-are-there-in-the-complete-graph-k-n-f?noredirect=1&lq=1  Each cycle will correspond to one of your table-arrangements.

Comment: if I take the rule n-1/2 and take n as the number of meetings, I still don't understand how to combine both n and 2n! so it would make sense or do you take n as the number of people so you'd get 2n-1/2. Perhaps I could use the permutation rule getting 2n!/n!?

Comment: Don't try to count anything.  This question is not about counting.  This question is about trying to prove at least one pattern exists.  Ross already gave the example with 5 people... now, move on to the case of 7 people.  Can you have people A,B,C,D,E,F,G sitting around a table?  Sure, one example is in that order ABCDEFG.  Can we do that again, but this time avoiding having any pair of letters who were together before be together again?  For instance **AB**DFCGE would not be allowed since AB was already in the first seating arrangement.

Comment: We could do it however... for example as ACEGBDF.  Now... can we do it *a third time?*  And do it in a way to avoid any pairs that appeared in any of the earlier arrangements?  It so happens that, yes, we can if we are careful.  We could have done a third arrangement as ADGCFBE.  Now, I happened to pick those specific arrangements for a reason, and they followed a particular pattern.  It is up to you to find how I chose those, and see if that same pattern works for all numbers of people... and in the event it doesn't work for all numbers, then to figure out how to modify it further.